# Unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'long' and 'unicode'

Tags: python

I am trying to do string replacement

```
self.cursor.execute("select (1) from eScraperInterfaceApp_scrapeddata where productURL = '%s' limit 1") % URL
```

error

> Unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'long' and 'unicode'

productURL is unicode so how do i replace it ... Can someone please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is doing:

```
self.cursor.execute("SQL template") % URL
```

It should be:

```
self.cursor.execute("SQL template" % URL)
```

---

Change the position of `)`:

```
self.cursor.execute("select (1) from eScraperInterfaceApp_scrapeddata where productURL = '%s' limit 1" % URL)
```

---

**Actually more correct way is using query parameter (to prevent SQL injection):**

```
self.cursor.execute("select (1) from eScraperInterfaceApp_scrapeddata where productURL = %s limit 1", (URL,))
```

Comment: I'd say that the preferred way should instead be called the right way, and the former one still marked as incorrect.

Comment: Note that % formatting of strings is deprecated. If you use Python 2.6 or above, the preferred way is to use `.format()`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what database (and DBAPI driver) you use, but PEP 249 requires DBAPI to support parameter substitution, so it would be much better to use it instead of Python string formatting.

```
cursor.execute(
    "select (1) from eScraperInterfaceApp_scrapeddata where productURL = %s limit 1;",
     (URL,))
```

(Note missing quotes around parameter placeholder, and argument as a 1-tuple).

Comment: I believe the usual syntax is to use `?` for the unknown parameter (this may be DBAPI-specific, though).